# using regex to split Combobox entry into two variables

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am looking for some instructions.  I have a combobox that is being populated by a concatenation of two tables from a SQL database.  Example of the text: "The Wild - 11/16/2014 2:00 AM".  I am trying to have staA hold "The Wild" and staB "11/16/2014 2:00 AM".  The length.  I tried using a traditional string split on " - ", but this only return the first word.  Next I tried a regex statement:

```
Dim input As String = strA
Dim pattern As String = "-"

Dim substring() As String = Regex.Split(input, pattern)
For Each match As String In substring
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match)
Next
```

but am not sure how to verify that the split happened or how to access the information from the split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use groups to do things like this with regex.

This way you can detect the absence of the expected pattern to deal with other inputs.

```
pattern = "^(?<a>[^-]+) - (?<b>[^-]+)$"
dim m as match=regex.match(input,pattern)
dim a as string=""
dim b as string=""
if m.success then
    a=m.groups("a").value
    b=m.groups("b").value
end if
```